# Conflicting "ss" commands on OpenSuse?

Tags: opensuse, command, ss

I have OpenSuse 15.1 "Magic Leap" installed.

I noticed that there seems to be two conflicting commands named `ss`.

When I run `which ss`, I get this:

> /usr/sbin/ss

And when I try to inspect, notice this...

```
>* whatis ss
ss (8)               - another utility to investigate sockets
```

Which to me looks like the `iproute2` command I expect - a modern replacement to `netstat` and the like. However, attempts to use this said command to for example list all active tcp connections on the machine show that the command in my default namespace is different!

See what happens with `ss -t`

```
>* ss -t
su: invalid option -- 't'
Try 'su --help' for more information.
```

Which to me looks like `ss` is *now* an alias for `su`, the super user util.

So, is this an OpenSuse "feature", bug or what?

Also, invoking the command from an unprivileged shell automatically summons `sudo` and leaves me on a root shell - further hinting at the later possibility!

I don't wish to install a deprecated `netstat` if there's a new, modern way to do things, but then, how do I get to the *proper* `ss` command?

---

**UPDATE:**

As per muru's suggestion, here's the output of `type -a`

```
>* type -a ss
ss is aliased to `sudo su'
ss is /usr/sbin/ss
ss is /usr/bin/ss
```

Further, upon inspection with `file`, I find that these two "versions" of ss reported above, actually are the same. See the following...

```
>* file /usr/bin/ss
/usr/bin/ss: symbolic link to ../sbin/ss
>* file /usr/sbin/ss
/usr/sbin/ss: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=4cb972d442c793ac1783b508f94e7aaceaf83088, stripped
>* /usr/sbin/ss --version
ss utility, iproute2-ss170705
```

So, at the same time, ss seems to be an alias for `sudo su`, yet upon inspection, seems to be the `iproute2` command. *Weird.*

Comment: Add the output of `type -a ss`, please.

Comment: @muru, check update.

Comment: And now use methods in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322459/70524 to see where that alias is set (chances are, openSUSE didn't)

Comment: @muru, thanks! Trying @thrig's proposal to check with `bash -ixlc : 2>&1 | grep ss` showed I had defined an alias `ss` in my bash.bashrc.local a long while ago ;-) I've now made the update, and it's now fine.

Comment: As a side note, `sudo su` is a strange command to use anyway. It translates as "_Hello `sudo`, please can I have root ... ah thankyou. Now then, hello `su`. Although I'm now already root, please can I have root ... thank you_". There is no need for the `su` because at that point you are already root. Perhaps you intended `sudo -s`?

Comment: @nemesisfixx Please post that as an answer!

Comment: @roaima, that's quite funny, but true! OMG ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I followed the suggestions of @muru, and after trying [@thrig's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322468/21688) proposal to check with `bash -ixlc : 2>&1 | grep ss` found I had defined an alias `ss` in my `/etc/bash.bashrc.local` a long while ago - a curious

```
alias ss="sudo su"
```

which, as @roima hilariously pointed out, was likewise overkill ;-) 
I've now made the necessary update to my local bashrc, and I get the correct `ss`.

Thanks guys!