# Something defined a command on macOS

Tags: bash, alias, macos

I made a mistake of installing some tool dependent on Go and it somehow redefined my `go` executable to `/usr/local/bin/go` from `/usr/local/go/bin/go`. I deleted the `/usr/local/bin/go`, cleaned the paths, called

```
eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
```

And it helped. But after every restart the problem mysteriously reappears. The `go` is in path, seen by `which` but when I call it, it goes to a wrong (deleted) executable.

```
$ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
$ go
-bash: /usr/local/bin/go: No such file or directory
```

The `/etc/paths.d` does not have anything interesting:

```
$ ls -l /etc/paths.d
total 16
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  23 Nov 17 16:45 100-rvictl
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  13 Oct 26  2016 40-XQuartz
```

Alias is not defined:

```
$ alias
alias gohome='cd $GOHOME'
```

Nothing interesting in `.bash_profile`. I can get around the problem but I would rather fix the source. Any suggestions as to where to look? Thanks!

This is macOS 11.3, bash (not zsh).

**Update**:

```
$ type go
go is hashed (/usr/local/go/bin/go)
```

This is after I ran `` eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s` `` .

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322459/117549 may be helpful

Comment: Please post the output of `type go` and `ls -l /usr/local/go/bin/go` and `(set -x; go)`